# add a comma after every "%" symbol using regex in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

if i have a value like this :

> C:100% B:90% A:80%

i want to add comma after every % so the output is like this :

> C:100%,B:90%,A:80%

i've tried somthing like :

```
data['Final'] = data['Final'].str.replace(r'(%)\n\b', r'\1,', regex=True)
```

Comment: What did happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re.sub` method from the `re` module in Python to achieve this.

```
import re

# Your original string
string = "C:100% B:90% A:80%"

# Use regex to replace all occurrences of '%' with ',%'
string = re.sub("%", ",%", string)

# The resulting string will be: "C:100%, B:90%, A:80%"
```

If you want to apply this to a column in a DataFrame, you can use the apply method to apply the regex substitution to each value in the column. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Create a DataFrame with a column of strings
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": ["C:100% B:90% A:80%", "D:70% E:60% F:50%"]})

# Use the apply method to apply the regex substitution to each value in the column
df["values"] = df["values"].apply(lambda x: re.sub("% ", "%,", x))
```

This will result in a DataFrame with the following values in the values column:

```
0    C:100%,B:90%,A:80%
1    D:70%,E:60%,F:50%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
df['final']= df['final'].str.replace(r'%\s*\b', r'%,', regex=True)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                final
0  C:100%,B:90%,A:80%
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no newline in your example data, so you could write the pattern matching just a space, or 1 or more whitespace chars `\s+`

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Final": ["C:100% B:90% A:80%"]})
data['Final'] = data['Final'].str.replace(r'(%) \b', r'\1,', regex=True)
print(data)
```

Output

```
                Final
0  C:100%,B:90%,A:80%
```